# cvblob and cvBlobsLib

Tags: ros, opencv, tracking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use [cvblob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) or [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) with ROS?

If yes, how can I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42268/cvblob-and-cvblobslib/) by [perr0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3067/perr0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [perr0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3067/perr0/) on 2012-08-28**:
Well, I was able to find the blobs using this code: http://nghiaho.com/?p=1102. But then I need to track them and I'm having a hard time trying to make ir. I can find their centroids, but I loose track of which is which during program execution.

**Comment by [perr0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3067/perr0/) on 2012-08-28**:
@pgorczak, does this SimpleBlobDetector have tracking capabilities? As far as I could understand reading the link you provided, it does not, but maybe you have seen something in this regard.

**Comment by [perr0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3067/perr0/) on 2012-08-28**:
That's why I was trying to use cvBlob, as it has "Basic blob tracking" out of the box.

**Comment by [pgorczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3055/pgorczak/) on 2012-08-29**:
The beauty of the new OpenCV is, that you can plug in any matcher behind the blob detector. A simple k-nearest-neighbors (knn) matcher could be enough. cvBlob probably does something like that in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to run blob detection with OpenCV, I would recommend taking a look at [SimpleBlobDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#SimpleBlobDetector : public FeatureDetector). You can easily convert any ROS image message to an OpenCV-Mat using [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) and take it from there.

If the above mentioned detector suits your needs, I'll give you more details on how to make it work.

---

Originally posted by [pgorczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3055/pgorczak/) with karma: 446 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-06-13**:
Can you please give the more details about that. I have converted the ros image into opencv-mat using cv_bridge. What shall i do next i.e. how i can configure or install cvblobs with ROS and what depencies shall i add in package.xml and also the in cmakelist !  I am using ROS-Hydro